# Export HTML table to Excel using php (NO MYSQL)

Tags: php, html, excel, export

OK so here's whats up. I want to be able bring up data from file and portray that in a table, then I want to be able to take a copy of that data and place that inside a Excel file.

This is where it gets a little harder:

I only want to use Html and PHP.

No MySQL or anything else.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: How did this receive so many upvotes? Honestly, how many of your friends and/or sock puppets help you here?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner crazy things happen here at night, especially in the php tag.

Comment: *Aye*, for sure @miken32 then the moon comes out and everybody's all over the place like flies.